# Flash Air Android transfer data via bluetooth

Tags: actionscript-3, air, bluetooth

it is possible to transfer data via bluetooth in Air Flash with as3? I want to make an application that is able to share data like some strings between 2 devices. I search on google, but I don't found same concret thing. I'm waiting for same solutions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using AIR, but it might be possible using an AIR Native Extension (ANE). Basically, you would need to do the data transfer via native Android (Java) and the ANE would be the bridge between the Java and the ActionScript. I searched for an ANE a few weeks ago to do this while scoping out a project and was able to find a few through Google, but I didn't test any of them myself.

Comment: thank you for replay...can you tell me some principles for using Air Native Extensions I'm new in this, I know you are more experimented than me. thanks

Comment: I found this ANE it is ok? what do you think ?http://as3breeze.com/bluetooth-ane/

Comment: StackOverflow really is not the place for that. Adobe has dozens of tutorials available and there are other resources available as well. Do some research. If you have a specific question (more than just how to do something), you can open another question here.